# PHP: Should JWT shared key be unique For each User?

Tags: php, authentication, jwt

I am creating an API and am using Token authentication with `firebase/php-jwt` for the first time, I wonder, should the key used to seed token be unique for all users or should it be same.

I realise that making it unique posses problem when decrypting, because at the time the information about the user is encrypted in the token.

So I wonder which is the right way to handle the token key.